# Tensor product of $n$ modules with minimal assumptions

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

> Let $R_1,\ldots, R_n$ be (commutative) rings, and $M_1 , \ldots, M_n$ be modules. What are the minimal assumpsions about the rings and modules needed in order to define a tensor product
> $M_1 \otimes_{R_1} M_2 \otimes _{R_2} \otimes\dots\otimes_{R_n} M_n$?

I am aware of an existing [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182048/definition-of-the-tensor-product-of-finite-sequence-of-modules). However, I am mainly looking for a reference that deals with a similar construction. In particular, I am looking for a proof of that the module structure ($(R_1,\ldots,R_n)$-multi-module structure?) is well-defined, and the universal property
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{(R_1, ..., R_n)}(M_1 \otimes_{R_1}\dots\otimes_{R_n} M_n,P) \cong \operatorname{Mult}_{(R_1, ..., R_n)}(M_1,\ldots,M_n; P)$$

Where $P$ is an Abelian group with a structure of a $R_i$-module for each $i$, and $\operatorname{Mult}_{(R_1, ..., R_n)}(M_1,\ldots,M_n; P)$ is the set of maps which are $R_i$-linear in the $i$'th coordinate.

Comment: You really just need that $M_1$ is a right $R_1$-module, $M_2$ is a $(R_1,R_2)$-bimodule, $M_3$ is a $(R_2,R_3)$-bimodule, ..., and $M_n$ is a left $R_n$-module.

Comment: And how do you see that multiplication by and $r_i$ is well-defined?

Comment: Also, do we need the multilinear map to be defined otherwise? Namely, not only $R_i$-linear in the $i$'th coordinate, but also $R_{i-1}$-linear?

Comment: The tensor product will *not* be a module over any of the $R_i$'s in general. Consider the smallest nontrivial case: you want to define $M \otimes_R N$. You need $M$ to be a right $R$-module and $N$ to be a left $R$-module. The resulting object $M \otimes_R N$ is just an abelian group -- there is no remaining module structure.